# How to use xbindkeys?

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, xbindkeys

I am trying to run Chromium when "Ctrl + shift + Alt + p" is pressed. I Install xbindkeys and xbindkey-config. Next, creating a file at home directory (`touch ~/.xbindkeysrc`), then set it as default (`xbindkeys --defaults > /home/pi/xbindkeysrc`). Then added this code to the file:

```
"chromium"
F8 | m:OxO + c:74
```

Following [Archlinux's tutorial](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xbindkeys), I used `xbindkeys --poll-rc` to reload the configuration file and apply the changes. Finally killed and reload the xbindkeys(`killall xbindkeys; xbindkeys`).

But, when F8 is pressed, Chromium does not launch on the Raspberry Pi

Answer (score 1):

For creating that file you use this command

```
$ xbindkeys -d > ~/.xbindkeysrc
```

Make sure to remove the already existing file you created, then run the command

Tip: After you made a change, execute `xbindkeys --poll-rc` to reload the configuration file and apply the changes.

Everything should work I think, and you will see some basic syntax highlighting

For more info check the arch wiki, I'm just reading it from there

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xbindkeys#Configuration